# JQuery displaying only certain id Div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a jquery function which displays a div, when an anchor tag with the id toggle_(some unique number) is clicked.

```
    $("a[id ^= 'toggle']").click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        $("div [id ^= 'replypost']").toggle();
    });
```

1. Each of the ids `toggle` and`"replypost` end with `_(unique number) for each id so I can separate all of the toggle and replypost divs.
2. The toggle and reply post divs are displayed through a 
           while() loop.So there are multipe `Toggle` and `replypost` divs but each of them have a unique number.
3. So there is a `toggle_1` and a `ReplyPost_1` .

I need a way to display only `ReplyPost_1` when `Toggle_1` is clicked and only `ReplyPost_2` when `Toggle_2`  is clicked, is this possible? If you need me to clear anything up just let me know and thanks for your time.

Comment: Well, you have three pretty much identical answers. I think you should know what to do now...

Comment: yea they worked thanks

Comment: Any time I see one of these `something_#` element ID schemes, I usually think of a case where the user is thinking in an old javascript paradigm and not really embracing the jQuery way of doing things.  If you could show your actual source output, I would bet you could get great suggestions on how to do away with that ID numbering scheme altogether.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To display only the post with a matching numeric and hide the others.

```
$("a[id^='toggle']").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $("[id^='replypost']").hide();
    $("#replypost_" + this.id.replace('toggle_', '') ).show();
});
```

But if the posts are siblings this is less to write:

```
$("a[id^='toggle']").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $("#replypost_" + this.id.replace('toggle_', '') ).show().siblings().hide();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this should do the trick:

```
$("a[id ^= 'toggle']").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $("div [id='replypost_"+$(this).attr('id').replace('toggle_','')+"']").show();
});
```

Comment: Thanks man that worked can you explain a little bit so I understand, but thanks really appreciate it.

Comment: With using $(this).attr('id'), I got the id of clicked element (let's say toggle_2). Then using replace function of string I removed toggle_, so I got 2.I hope this explanation is sufficient. But if not please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("a[id^='toggle']").click(function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  // grab the index of the clicked element from it's ID
  var index = $(this).attr('id').match(/\d+$/)[0]
  // identify the thing to toggle uniquely, based on the grabbed index
  $("div#replypost_"+index).toggle();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use classes to make this alot cleaner, and eliminate the loops.

```
<a id="toggle_1" class="toggle" />
<div id="replyPost_1" class="reply-post" />
```

Now you can just listen to a click event on *all* toggle anchors, get the number from the id, hide all reply divs and show only the matching reply post.

```
$(".toggle").click(function(e) {
  var num = $(this).attr("id").split("_")[1];
  $(".reply-post").hide();
  $("replyPost_"+num).show();
});
```